# Creating a Tridiagonal Matrix given 2 Vectors in Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab, tridiagonal-matrices

I'm new to Matlab (coming from Python), and I'm trying to figure out the following matrix $A$ given 2 input arrays, $a = [a_0, a_1, ... , a_{n-1}]$, and $b = [b_1, b_2, ... , b_n]$.

[image: Matrix A]

I tried `diag(a) - diag(sqrt(b)) - diag(sqrt(b))` going off another MSE post I read, but this doesn't seem to work. What's the correct way to do this in MATLAB? I would just create $n$ arrays and fill them up to represent columns in Python, but I'm sure there's a much smarter way to do that in MATLAB. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the matlab page for the diag command.  You need to use two arguments: diag(v,k) places the elements of vector v on the kth diagonal.  So, something like
A = diag(v,0)+diag(sqrt(b),-1)+diag(sqrt(b),1).